# Insert data with time slicing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-insert

I have example table like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+-------+
| Start date   | End date     | State |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
|20131205 10:00|20131205 11:00| A     |
|20131205 11:00|20131205 12:00| B     |
|20131205 12:00|20131205 13:00| C     |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
```

I would like to insert new state (D) in way that is shown below:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------+
| Start date   | End date     | State  |
+--------------+--------------+--------+
|20131205 10:00|20131205 11:00| A      |
|20131205 11:00|20131205 11:20| B      |
|20131205 11:20|20131205 11:40| D (NEW)|
|20131205 11:40|20131205 12:00| B      |
|20131205 12:00|20131205 13:00| C      |
+--------------+--------------+--------+
```

It means that if I have other state (B) in this same time as new state (D) then old state (B) should be sliced in time.

How can I achieve this?

(I am using MS SQL Server 2008)

Comment: Trigger "instead of insert, update"?

Comment: How would the result table look like if the `End date` of `D` record is `20131205 13:00`?

Comment: What If the time frame for inserted record intersects B and D for example  `11:20-12:30`?

Comment: @gotqn and valex I answered you by "Add Another Answer" option because I had a problem with formatting tables. Sorry for disorder.

Comment: @Adrian Do you need the records to be ordered in this way?

Comment: @gotqn It has to be exactly like in example result.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solutions is to use a [trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) - the trigger is a special kind of stored procedure that automatically executes when an event occurs in the database server.

In your situation you can use `instead of insert` event - the procedure is going to be executed each time a new record needs to be inserted in your table and `overwrites` the standart insert operation itself.

*What will the trigger do?*

The screenshot below displays the possible scenarios:

[image]

where `A, B, C, D` and `E` are rows already insearted in your table and `X, Y` and `Z` are new rows to be instered - all displayed in the same timeline.

*Handlng the situations*

1. **X** cases - the *start* and the *end* dates do not overlap any exising *start* and *end* dates records. This is the easiest case, because you only need to insert the new record.
2. **Y** cases - both the *start* and the *end* dates are in existing period. You should:

   - insert the new **Y** record
   - insert new **E** record with **E** star date and **Y** star date
   - update the exiting **E** record start date to **Y** end date
3. **Z** cases - the inserted record *start* and *end* dates overlap several existing periods:

   - insert the new record
   - check in which period the new record *start* date belongs and upate its *end* date to new record *start* date
   - check in which period the new record *end* date blongs and upated its *start* date to new record *end* date
   - delete all periods which *start* and *end* dates are in the new recod period

This should not be complecated to you - only some `IF` statements with dates comparisons.

Some advice - you are  free to add the logic above in separate SQL procedure and when you need to insert new record to call it. This is better, because we are skipping the `trigers` part.

And finally, when you are extracting records frm the table you need to sort it by `Start date` column - it is formated well and will do the trick to get the records in the order you like.

Answer (score 0):

@gotqn
If the 'End date' of D record is 20131205 13:00 result table should look like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------+
| Start date   | End date     | State  |
+--------------+--------------+--------+
|20131205 10:00|20131205 11:00| A      |
|20131205 11:00|20131205 11:20| B      |
|20131205 11:20|20131205 13:00| D (NEW)|
+--------------+--------------+--------+
```

@valex
"If the time frame for inserted record intersects B and D for example 11:20-12:30"
In this case result should be like:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------+
| Start date   | End date     | State  |
+--------------+--------------+--------+
|20131205 10:00|20131205 11:00| A      |
|20131205 11:00|20131205 11:20| B      |
|20131205 11:20|20131205 12:30| E (NEW)|
|20131205 12:30|20131205 13:00| C      |
+--------------+--------------+--------+
```